# Listing and deleting newly created file

Tags: java, file

I'm using some 3rd party code in my own code, which creates some files in folder. The files are there in the directory but when I list them or try to delete them within the same program session (run) I can not do that.
But in the next newer run of the program I'm able to list and delete these older files but it still won't work with the files created in that session. What could be the reason?

Here is the piece of code which lists and delete the files.

```
private void clearWorkspace(File workSpace) { 
 // Delete copied files and generated results from the work space 
 //clearing work space 
 foreach file in workSpace.listFiles() { 
  if (file.isDirectory()) { 
   foreach f in file.listFiles() { 
    f.delete(); 
  } 
 } else {  
   file.delete(); 
  } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: That is not Java `foreach file in` ^^

Comment: I know this is code written in JetBrains' MPS. Which has different foreach syntax.

Comment: Foreach statement is not the problem, the code is compiling and running fine.

Comment: It won't work if you have folder in folder in folder in folder ... you may use recursivity

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably, that your external program still has a [handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_%28computing%29) on the files you want to delete. If the external program uses for example a file writer, it has to close this filewriter before you are able to delete the file.

Comment: My guess is also that. But till now I'm not able to find any handle in the 3rd party code which isn't closed. But I'll continue with search. Thanks

Comment: Beside input files streams and output file streams are there any other handles which I should look for?

Comment: I don't have an idea what else you could check for. However, if you use unix, you can list the handles a specific program has using `lsof -p YOURPID`

Comment: Ok thanks. I have one more question if you know the answer. Is there a way to close all streams or handles at once in Java without having references to them? Or is there a way to close all handles (streams) associated with particular File having reference of that File in Java?

Comment: A `File`in Java is nothing but a nice convenient representation of a file path. I think you could somehow find a solution closing the file handles of a process using operating system tools. But this would include the danger of data loss and there is good reason why Java doesn't allow this. 

Try to find the unclosed file handles using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FindBugs and close them.

Answer (score 0):

Here,you have written the code which will help you only 2 level of folder hierarchy.

Java provides the way to delete the directory. Use the below code you don't need any loop for that.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(destination));
```

Documentation is [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

And check the permission if there is any other problem with permission or user the clearing the workspace.